# How to hide a tag after given speciffic condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have this Handlebars template:

```
<div class="card-body">          
  <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ this.group }}
    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"> </i> {{ this.name }} {{ this.lastName }}
  </h5>
  <a href="https://wa.me/{{ this.phone }}"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ this.phone }}</a><br>
  <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ this.address }} <br>
  <a href="mailto:{{ this.email }}"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ this.email }}</a> 
  <br>          
  <hr>
  <p class="card-text">  
    <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/{{ this.facebook }}" > <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/{{ this.instagram }}" ><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/{{ this.twitter }}"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/{{ this.linkedIn }}"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><br>                
  </p>
</div>
```

And I want to hide all "a" tags that won't get a "href" value.

I've tried this, for instance-

```
<script>                           
    if (!document.getElementsByClassName("facebook").value) {      
      $(".facebook").hide();
    }    
</script>
```

But it hides all "a" tags, no matter if the comply with the condition or not. I'm guessing that it must be something to do with iterate each generated tag, but I can't figure out how to target them.

Comment: All your `<a>` elements have a `href` value. Could you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve? What's the underlying logic of showing/hiding your tags?

Comment: @William approach, that was it to get closer to what I want. Answering @tao, what was trying to do is to set active or inactive the `href` only if the user filled the input for the specific site (say, facebook) with their user. But, as well putted by you, I was already setting all my `href`s with the first part of the url, so then it gets completed with the response from the db. Now, what I must achieve is actually to append the first part of the url afterwards, not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to it using `each`:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("href") == "") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Learn more: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Yes, @William did it. Made me think to validate the url on user creation, instead of after. Thank you!